# How is the empty set represented as union of basis elements?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $T$ is a topology generated by a basis $B$. Then each open set in $T$ can be represented as union of basis elements. But how is empty set a union of basis elements?

Comment: $\varnothing = \bigcup_{U \in \varnothing} U$

Comment: The answer is too precise. I cannot understand.  Can you please explain? An example would be helpful.

Comment: It's worth commenting that the result of a union of no sets is defined to be the empty set for convenience. Similarly, we consider the sum of no numbers to be $0$ and the product of no numbers to be $1$.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @TheoBendit: It's not really a convenience. Given any family of sets $\mathcal{A}$ its union $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ is defined to be $\{ x : ( \exists A \in \mathcal{A} ) ( x \in A ) \}$. If $\mathcal{A} = \varnothing$, then $( \exists A \in \mathcal{A} ) ( x \in A )$ is false for all $x$, meaning that $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ must be empty.

Comment: @TheoBendit see my answer for proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll clarify what the other answer lacks:
The expression $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ means:

$x\in A\iff \exists i\in I:x\in A_i$

Let us take: $$A=\bigcup_{i\in\emptyset}\text{potato}$$
Then $x\in A\iff \exists i\in \emptyset:x\in\text{potato}$

But wait! There DOES NOT EXIST an $i\in \emptyset$ so we can never have $x\in A$

We can never have the $\exists i\in\emptyset$ part - so it doesn't matter if it's potatoes or BASIS SETS - you can't have them

If we can never have anything in $A$ then $A=\emptyset$

This completes the proof.

Comment: We have the potato again which we discussed earlier@Alec

Comment: @Rememberme it's an abstraction. You know how we use $x$ rather than say numbers to mean "the value doesn't matter" - Potato is like algebra of algebra, it means nothing matters. I'm not sure if I sound wise or high.

Comment: You sound great @Alec I understand you :)

Comment: This is nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Rememberme the potato illustrates well that "You can put whatever you want here, it matters not" - I encourage you to do this. Potatoes are great because if you need two you can choose $\text{spud}$ where as with say, oranges, there is no other type! Potatoes truly are the future of algebra.

Comment: Also valid, deserved the tick. Very clear and well laid out.

Answer (score 9):

The union of nonempty sets is a nonempty set. But there are are no nonempty sets and hence the union is empty. As stated , it is a empty union of nonempty sets.
$$\emptyset = \bigcup_{V\in \emptyset}V$$

Comment: Basis doesn't have empty set. So how do we take union of empty set?

Comment: Well an empty set is the subset of every set

Comment: @divya The only empty set on the right is the *index* set, which need not be an element of the basis, but a subset of it

Comment: The answer is worded incorrectly.  This is not a union of empty sets.  There are not empty sets among the $V$.  Correctly put it is an empty union of non-empty sets.  Each set in the union is non-empty -- but there are none of them!

Comment: So, empty set is a union of absolutely nothing from the basis.  So it is empty I think I got it correctly.

Comment: Oh thanks for that @ColinMcLarty  I will edit it

Comment: See my answer @divya